# Wireshark : unable to catch network traffic to/from a device

Tags: networking, wireshark, sniffing

I would like to use Wireshark to catch data to/from a device on my network.

I have a connected devices (all based on a ESP8266) which have trouble getting out the sleep mode (I think it's that). So I would like to send command, periodically, to avoid this sleep mode on these devices.

To catch incoming or out-coming data, I tried to use Wireshark.
I use a filter ip.src_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is IP address of my device) or ip.dst_host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, I tested with a simple ping and it works.
But when I ask to Alexa to power on or power off, I can't see data because my Macbook (10.13.6) or PC (Windows10) are not sources of the requests.

I checked, the "promiscuous" checkbox is enabled when I choose interface.

So I think I forgot something, but what ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You can’t see traffic of other devices on your network unless it is directly between your device and the other device. The only traffic you will see are broadcasts.

All modern Ethernet networks are connected together via network switches. Network switches are more efficient specifically because they do NOT send the traffic to every computer on the network. They “discover” what computer is plugged in to which port and send the traffic directly between two devices. In this way, large networks operate more efficiently by avoiding the collisions that typically would occur if multiple computers were trying to send data out on to a network at the same time. It is also a significant security concern that one computer could view the traffic of another computer.

If you want to see the traffic between devices on your network you will need to account for the restrictions of your network switch.

1. Use a network hub instead. This device mirrors all traffic on all ports. Good luck finding one. Searching for “network hub” just finds network switches the manufacturer decided to throw the word “hub” on. See [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HubReference) what wireshark has to say about this.
2. Use a mirror or monitor port on a higher end network switch.
3. ARP spoof the network to “trick” computers in to sending all their data to you.
4. Tap in to the physical wire plugged in to the device you want to monitor to create a splitter where your network card operates in passive mode listening to the traffic.

Nowadays, #2 is the most common way to accomplish what you want, but requires a switch that is higher end than most soho routers/switches.

For strictly experimental purposes with no extra hardware, but significantly more complication, you could use option #3.

Comment: Regarding #1, see [Wireshark's Hub Reference](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HubReference)

Comment: Thank you very much for these explanations ! It's a wifi plug (sorry it was missing information from my post), so I can't use option 1, 2 and 4 but it's very instructive, I didn't know that. I think also that the solution 3 will not a cakewalk because requests are coming from outside servers (Alexa or Google). To do that I must simulate the plug based on known information by servers (mac address maybe). I didn't imagine it's so complex :/

Answer (score 1):

on windows: you must execute wireshark as admin (then you will see the devices)

on linux as root or "sudo" if your user account is in the sudoers file to run wireshark with root permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did it for Windows and OSX. Your answer makes me think it strange, I can see all others request on my network (tv, NAS, etc, ...) but not these devices... strange...

Comment: Could depend on type of protocol used by your devices, and perhaps the router/switch configuration.